# How to auto fill cmd prompt

Tags: c#, cmd

I Have a C# program; when I hit a button I want it to open a CMD window, then automatically type in the cmd window and run that said command. So far I have this from 4 hours of research. But nothing is working.

```
 Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        //p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;            
        p.Start();

        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("ipconfig");
```

Any idea on how to fill in a certain text then automatically run it when the button is hit?

Comment: "when the button is hit"? What button? I thought your program is remote-controlling a command prompt window...? (Btw why don't you just start `ipconfig` as a separate process directly and redirect its standard *output*? What are you actually trying to achieve in the end? Perhaps your current solution is more complicated than it needs to be.)

Comment: Just trying to learn. When a button is hit it opens a cmd and runs a command.

Answer (score 2):

With `StandardInput` and `StandardOutput` redirected, you cannot see the new window opened. If you want to create a new `cmd` window and run `ipconfig` in it, you could do this:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ipconfig & pause";
p.Start();
```

Comment: @ColinCappetto Glad to help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that if all you want to do is execute "ipconfig" you could just invoke it instead of cmd.exe.  Assuming you want to do other things with cmd.exe, here is an example of how to invoke it, have it execute a command, and then terminate (using the /K switch instead of /C will keep cmd.exe running):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C ipconfig";
            p.Start();

            var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Write(output);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use the `cmd.exe` at all and not just do `p.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe"`? If you are going to redirect the standard output and not create a new separate console window there is no reason to start `cmd.exe`